# How to filter views results by value of profile field of currently logged in user?

Tags: views, users

When I create a user a 'supplier' must be selected. When a user creates a product a 'supplier' must also be selected. Now I would like to show all the products with supplier = supplier logged in user. I now have a table with all my products listed, but now I need to add the filter. Is there a module for this or can this be done in another way? Because when I now want to add a filter only the product fields are shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of listing products filtered by Supplier field. You want to build your View from Users and add a relationship to Products linked through your Supplier field -- see this thread with further documentation:
https://drupal.org/node/1111722

So its something like the following from my above link:

> - Create a user view.
> - Add a contextual filter on user: uid. If no filter value is present, build a default value using the currently logged in user. (This will
>     give you exactly one user object in your view -- the logged in user.)
> - Add a relationship, using the relevant taxonomy reference field on the user accounts. This will bring you information about the
>     "interest" term for the logged in user.
> - Add another relationship, called "term: nodes marked with term" (or something like that). This will bring you information about all nodes
>     marked with the interest term for the logged in user.
> - Either set the view to display node teasers, or select a number of fields to display.
> - Add a display as usual. Done!

Alternatively you could use [Views Global Filter](http://drupal.org/project/global_filter) to set a filter based on the profile value most likely.